# How to save Values to a NSDictionary

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I need to know;

1.) how to save values to a NSDictionary, and in Key-Value pairs. I have the following keys and values to be saved to a single NSDictionary

> Key  ------ Value
>
> "1" ------- "One"
>
> "2" -------"Two"
>
> "3" -------- "Three" etc..

2.) Later i need to save the above NSDictionary to a NSArray. Is this possible ?

3.) Is there a way to Order the above NSDictionary in Assending order. How can i do this

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. `[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:@"value", @"key", @"value", @"key2", nil]`
2. `[dict allKeys]` or `[dict allValues]`
3. A dictionary is a map from a value to a key. Ordering does not make sense. If you get the keys from the dictionary, you can sort the values in that as you would an ordinary `NSArray`

Comment: I need to add one key-value at a time. Is this possible ?

Comment: Not with an NSDictionary. You'd have to use an NSMutableDictionary instead.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use a `NSMutableDictionary` instance. There are methods like `:setObject:forKey`

https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/nsmutabledictionary_Class/Reference/Reference.html

After you add dictionary values to an `NSMutableArray` instance, you can use the following method to sort them.

```
[arrayInstance sortUsingSelector:@selector(localizedCaseInsensitiveCompare:)];
```

Comment: Dmitry is probably right that you'll want to use a *mutable* dictionary and add key-values as you go along, but this is not an absolute requirement. If you have all your values assembled at the outset, you can use NSDictionary's initWithObjects:forKeys initializer. NSArray has similar initializers. Also note: Your example values can be instantiated as NSString, which is an object and can be added directly to dict/array collections. But if your values are ints or floats, you will need to wrap them in NSNumber, and if they are structs like CGRect, you will need to wrap them in NSValue.